# Database Schema for a multiplayer quiz game

Tags: design, database, database-design, sql, postgres

I'm trying to accomplish this scenario :

There are 2 types of users, let's say `Admin` and `Worker`, and there have different roles.

Admin can do a `CRUD` of questions, and also can create a room where the users can join to play together (this is just a name) but maybe is a good idea to create more attributes inside of it like, WHO is playing in this room, POINTS for everyone but let's talk it afterwards when I show you the design.

Worker can play solo or multiplayer.

Ok the thing is, on my design I have :

Collection named `User` which contains :

1. _id
2. username
3. password

This is a default one, but then I'm wondering how do I define the `Role` if it's an `Admin` or a `Worker`, something like `isAdmin:true` and then I check this `Bool`? Also I'd like to have the reference for those questions where the user has failed more, I mean like a wrongQuestionNumber which contains the _id of the question and the times he/she failed

Then I'd like to have the `Question` collection where contains :

1. _id
2. question_name
3. answers[1,2,3,4]
4. correctAnswer or answers because it can be multi option chooser
5. topic
6. isExamQuestion

Then the `Room` collection should contains :

1. _id
2. name
3. capacity
4. type (game can be as a group or solo) that's why this attribute
5. exam (this is an object created by Admin means that when he creates a question he can select many and create an exam with those)
6. ranking (This is the top X from 1 to X)
7. don't think if I have to add the winner here because if I get the position 0 from ranking I get the winner...

There's a collection named `Topic` as well, if my question have a topic then I can select the question by Topic.
An example of Topic should me Math so user can do only exams or do tests with math questions.

1. _id
2. Name
3. Questions[...]

Then I have to store like a historic about what are the questions worker has answered correct and what did not, to make some statistics, but I need to store some historicals for Admin to see in this topic the average that Workers have failed more is : Question23 (for instance) something like that.

Any tip is welcome, and improvement as well.

### EDIT

@uokesita recommend to me to use `PostgreSQL` so maybe it's a good idea doing this way, how could be the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. You are making many general questions, which makes any answer very difficult. I propose to atack the problem in small pieces, and solve each.

A few remarks that came to my mind:

- your user collection should have a field with the type of user so you know what rights each user has.
- you can have a collection of events, with the user name and type of event.
- your case does not seems like a good fit for mongodb (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981753/when-to-use-mongodb)

Comment: Why it's not clear, is about creating the design of this database, and yes, maybe mongo is not the best option, then what should I use instead?

Comment: you ask many questions. For a good answer, you should ask one question in a clear form. Take a look at mariaDB, an open source sql database. They seem to have good documentation. Or just the SQL database that best integrates with whatever platform/language you are using. Don't overt think it.

Comment: Yes, but I mean it's just to how to design the database and if it's a good idea use mongodb or not

Answer (score -2):

ozᴉʞS, I agree with the others that MongoDB is "not good" for this scenario.
Not good meaning there is a better way to approach this, with MongoDB you will be complicating yourself and your work; I think you should use a traditional SQL database (MySQL, Postgres, SQLite, MariaDB, etc.)

I suggest you start with an entity-relationship diagram to define your data

https://www.smartdraw.com/entity-relationship-diagram/

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=es&sl=en&u=https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/learning-mysql/0596008643/ch04s04.html&prev=search

And then I suggest trying Postgres